# m_forward and m_side in counter strike global offensive?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, source-engine

What does m_forward and m_side do in counter strike global offensive?

m_forward is described as "Mouse forward factor"

m_side is described as "Mouse side factor"

However, i have changed these values to several different values and have noticed no difference. Values i have used are 0, 1, 0.5, 200, -200.

Answer (score 1):

With `cl_mouselook` (use mouse to look) disabled, mouse movements are interpreted as movement -when you move the mouse vertical and horizontal it makes you go forward and to the side.